# IE Whitespace like bug but isn't the whitespace bug

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, whitespace

I have a CSS menu setup here:

http://pans.saebermedia.com/

The problem is, I noticed IE doesn't display the menus properly, and now I'm back to using my computer to fix it which has IE8. I'm using compatibility mode.

I've noticed two problems. On the submenu, (Say "Resource Center"), there is extra spacing between each item that when your cursor passes through it closes the menu. This sounds like the IE Whitespace bug but I used PHP to strip out the White-space. If I use float:left;clear:left; it causes the menus to be in-equal lengths in Firefox and IE.

Anybody know what's going on?

Comment: Is this for IE6 or 7? Have you tried giving the links hasLayout using `zoom: 1` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested my solution only on IE 7.

in elements:

```
li.menu-item
```

you have to change

```
display:block;
```

to

```
display:inline;
```

Comment: It's working so I don't understand why someone's vote it down? Why you do that?

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that took me a bit. You should really reduce the amount of css that you are throwing at these elements. You are overwriting a lot of cascaded values, etc. However, there are 2 primary values that IE7 is having an issue with.

The first is `min-width` on `#main-nav > ul > li ul a`. For some reason IE7 having this value on the `a` is making it ignore that it is `display: block`. It's probably something related to the parent being misinteruputed as `inline-block` (see #2).

Second is the `display: inline-block` being inherited by the `li`s in the `.sub-menu` from the `li.menu-item` above `ul.submenu`. When I remove these items IE7 starts acting appropriately.

In all cases this has nothing to do with, what you call, the "IE Whitespace Bug". `inline-block` elements are treated no different than `inline` elements when the collapes of whitespace is calculated. [This is per the spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-text/#white-space-rules). IE does not have a bug, any browser that does not collapse whitespace to 1 single whitespace between `inline` and `inline-block` elements (without the use of [`bikesheding: discard`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-text/#bikeshedding)) is in violation of the spec.

Comment: @Rogue-Coder try my solution its easier:)

Comment: @lord_t, except it doesn't work. Adding `display:inline;` to an element containing an element that is `display: block` will cause other problems.

Comment: So you talking that, my answer is solution for the problem... Maybe not the best, but it is.